# ¿Se puede usar Heroku sin Maven?

Tags: java, aplicación-web, maven, heroku, netbeans-8.2

tengo una aplicacion web (`Java Web`) con `Netbeans 8.2` quiero subirla a `heroku` pero resulta que no lo puedo hacer, a medida que voy viendo me doy cuenta que necesito instalar `Maven` y no quiero, la aplicacion se pondria muy pesada. Sera posible hacerlo sin `Maven`. En el caso de que si, ¿Como hacerlo?Ademas necesito saber algun concepto sobre las aplicaciones en la `nube`, por no se mucho sobre el tema, por favor. Gracias

Comment: Porque se haría muy pesada?

Comment: Maven es pesado y necesita de muchas dependencias para funcionar.

Comment: en tiempo de desarrollo dices tu? porque el empaquetado es el mismo, con o sin maven

Answer (score 0):

Genera el .WAR y despliega el WAR, te dejo información del displegue del WAR

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment